# Связка dropdownlist с обьектом MVC через AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, mvc, dropdown

Здраствуйте,

Я пытаюсь подвязать dropdownlist к моему обьекту. Список элементов я беру через переменную lstTypes.
Когда я использую "track by" - тогда почему-то выбирается всегда последний элемент и нельзя изменить выбор в dropdownlist:

```
<select ng-model="Project.TypeID" id="Project.TypeID" ng-options="type.Value as type.Text for type in Project.lstTypes track by Project.TypeID">
```

Мой обьект в MVC:

```
namespace MyProject.ModelView
{
    public class ProjectModelView
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string NameEng{ get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        public int TypeID { get; set; }

        public List<ProjectType> _ProjectTypes;

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> lstTypes
        {
            get
            {
                _ProjectTypes = (from u in dal.DBProjectTypes select u).ToList<ProjectType>();
                return new SelectList(_ProjectTypes, "ID", "value");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

```js
<script>
    var app = angular.module('Proj', ['ngRoute'])

    app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

        $routeProvider
          .when('/Project/PEdit/:someId', {
              controller: 'projectDisplay'
          , templateUrl: 'tmpl-view-project'
          })
    })

    app.controller('projectDisplay', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

        $scope.route = {id:-1}
        if ($routeParams.someId != undefined) {
            $scope.route = { id: $routeParams.someId }
            console.log("1")
        }

        console.log($scope.route.id)

        if ($scope.route.id != -1) {
            console.log("3")

            $http({

                url: '/Project/GetProjectsByIDJSON',
                params: {
                    pID: $scope.route.id
                },
                method: 'get'
            }).then(function (data) {

                $scope.Project = data.data;

                $scope.Project.TypeID = parseInt($scope.Project.TypeID)

            })
        }

        $scope.Add = function () {
            $http({ method: "POST", data: $scope.Project.myProj, url: "/Project/Submit" }).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            })
        }
    })
</script>
И в конце файл CSHTML:
```

```html
<div ng-app="Proj" ng-controller="projectDisplay">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="tmpl-view-project">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <!-- accordion 1 -->
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <!-- panel-heading -->
                    <h4 class="panel-title" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <!-- title 1 -->
                        <a>
                            Project Details
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <!-- panel body -->
                <div id="accordionOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <!-- Project content -->
                    <div class="top-content">
                        <div class="inner-bg">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 form-box">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="form-last-name">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NameEng)</label>
                                            <input id="Project.NameEng" ng-model="Project.NameEng" name="Project.NameEng" type="text" class="form-first-name form-control" placeholder="Project name in english..." />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <select ng-model="Project.TypeID" id="Project.TypeID" ng-options="type.Value as type.Text for type in Project.lstTypes">
                                                <option value="">-- Choose Type --</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _Когда я использую "track by" - тогда почему-то выбирается всегда последний элемент и нельзя изменить выбор в dropdownlist_ - а это точно работает? и в консоли нет ошибок?